# .net core Cookie container. CookieException: Cookie format error

Tags: c#, setcookie

I have the following cookie:

```
"IBCOOKIE03=IBCOOKIE03VALUERAND769h0eeGn2PIMCHMdshOqNxAj59dCURz, TLCookie=RANDdIOHjTu2oXRBX2sSCnlKYARsHqHFbJjI, $Version=1; IBCOOKIE02=365bc6349dcd96adec19b7eb665ff151ec3cc93f1ac391dc541f6547f5d5ce238f2ba5f63731959d8f21c27cfaac4674ELz13r0hTA20/waJkKYk0fTIXaemLDgV1Nzh18Di11g/9cTbkZNtNe57osQDladgWQpr2klf05mntV9iJBlFqA==; $Path=/; $Domain=.lloydsbank.co.uk"
```

I've seen online that setting version to 0 might help but it's still getting an error.

```
container.SetCookies(url, cookieString);
```

url is set to https://online.lloydsbank.co.uk/